# How to view white arrow in place of white space in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: desired]

I want my vscode editor to be seen like this instead it is showing white dots for space.
Please help.

Comment: The arrows indicate tabs.  So if you want arrows you have to use tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: I know but my tabs are also shown as spaces.

Answer (score 3):

In VS code
press `CTRL+SHIFT+P`
type "indentation"
select the option to "Convert indentation to tabs"

you can also make sizes for indentation

press `CTRL+SHIFT+P`

type `"indentation"`

select the option to `"indent using tabs"`

select size of any number ,ie, `4` or `5`

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the solution. I installed Tabstop Whitespace Converter. On installing, run Convert Spaces to Tabs command. It will convert the spaces to tabs and the white arrow is displayed now. Previously my tabs were being treated as spaces. Thanks anyway